# Yii2 redirect to specific tab from controller using url hash(#) or Fragment

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

This the relevant code in my form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin ( [ 'id' => 'dynamic-form' , 'layout' => 'horizontal' , 'enableClientValidation' => true , 'enableAjaxValidation' => true ] ); ?>
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body nav-tabs-animate nav-tabs-horizontal">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line" data-plugin="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li class="active" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#information" aria-controls="information" role="tab">
                    <?= Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Information' ); ?></a></li>    
            <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#rest_days" aria-controls="rest_days" role="tab">
                    <?= Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Rest Days' ); ?></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#instructor_schedule" aria-controls="instructor_schedule" role="tab">
                    <?= Yii::t ( 'app' , 'Instructor Schedule' ); ?></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the code in controller:

```
public function actionUpdate( $id ) {
    $model = $this->findModel ( $id );

    if ( $model->load ( Yii::$app->request->post () ) && $model->save () ) {
        Yii::$app->getSession ()->setFlash ( 'successClass' );
        // return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        return $this->redirect ( [ 'user/update-instructor' , 'id' => $model->instructor_id , '#' => 'instructor_schedule' ] );
    }
    return $this->render ( 'update' , [
                'model' => $model ,
    ] );
}
```

I want to redirect to the tab -`instructor_schedule`, it is redirecting correctly to `user/update-instructor`, but not going to the specific tab, but the first tab.

How I can achieve this?

**Update**
View file - `update_instructor.php`

```
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\User */
$tab='';
if (isset($_GET["tab"])){
$tab= $_GET['tab'];
}
if(!empty($tab)){
$this->registerJs ( "$('#dynamic-form .nav-tabs a[href=\"#".$tab."\"]').tab('show');" , yii\web\View::POS_READY );
}

$this->title = $title . ' ' . $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Instructors', 'url' => ['instructor']];
//$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->first_name.' '.$model->last_name, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->id]];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
$manager = User::find()->where(['user_role' => 'manager'])->andwhere(['status' => 10])->all();
$manager_array = ArrayHelper::map($manager, 'id',
    function ($model) {
        return $model->first_name . ' ' . $model->last_name . '(' . $model->manager->location['location_title'] . ')';
    });
?>



<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'dynamic-form', 'layout' => 'horizontal', 'enableClientValidation' => true, 'enableAjaxValidation' => true]);?>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body nav-tabs-animate nav-tabs-horizontal">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-line" data-plugin="nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="active" role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#information" aria-controls="information" role="tab">
          <?=Yii::t('app', 'Information');?>
        </a></li>

        <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#rest_days" aria-controls="rest_days" role="tab">
          <?=Yii::t('app', 'Rest Days');?>
        </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#instructor_schedule" aria-controls="instructor_schedule" role="tab">
          <?=Yii::t('app', 'Instructor Schedule');?>
        </a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#custom_break_time" aria-controls="custom_break_time" role="tab">
          <?=Yii::t('app', 'Break Time');?>
        </a></li>


......

<div class="tab-content"> <br clear="all">
        <!-- start information tab -->
        <div class="tab-pane active animation-slide-left" id="information" role="tabpanel">
.....

<?php
if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
    ?>
        <div class="tab-pane animation-slide-left" id="rest_days" role="tabpanel">
          <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
....

<?php
if (!$model->isNewRecord) {
    ?>
          <div class="tab-pane animation-slide-left" id="instructor_schedule" role="tabpanel">
              <?php $this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Class Durations');
              $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
            ?>

......

<?php
if (!$model->isNewRecord) { ?>
<div class="tab-pane animation-slide-left" id="custom_break_time" role="tabpanel">
 <?php   $this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Custom Break Times');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>

.....
```

controller - `ClassDurationController.php`

```
public function actionUpdate($id,$tab='information') {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('successClass');

            // return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                        return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor', 'id' => $model->instructor_id, 'tab' => 'instructor_schedule']);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,                        
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: are you using for tab `yii\jui\Tabs` widget ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing is that your hash `#` or `fragment` is resolved in the browser and never sent to the server, its reachable through javascript though.

If you are ok with changing your `fragment` to a `parameter` do the following.

I assume you are using bootstrap tabs.

1. Change your `actionUpdate($id)` to `actionUpdate($id,$tab='information')`.
2. Change the code for redirect to

   ```
   return $this->redirect(
       [
           'user/update-instructor', 
           'id' => $model->instructor_id, 
           'tab' => 'instructor_schedule'
       ]
   );
   ```
3. Then add the following inside your view file

   ```
   $js=<<<JS 
        $('#dynamic-form .nav-tabs a[href=\"#".$tab."\"]').tab('show');        
   JS;

   $this->registerJs ( $js , yii\web\View::POS_READY );
   ```

Now if your url is `http://www.yoursite.com/update?id=1` it will always show your the first tab and if `http://www.yoursite.com/update?id=1&tab=instructor_schedule` it will show the `instructor_schedule` tab or any other if valid name provided.

Hope this solves your problem.

### `EDIT`

You should remove the `active` class from the `li` and the `tabs` to disable the showing of the default tab and then switching to the selected issue, that is what causing it

see the 2 culprits below

```
<li class="active" role="presentation">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#information" aria-controls="information" role="tab">
        <?=Yii::t('app', 'Information');?>
    </a>
</li>
```

and the tab

```
<div class="tab-pane active animation-slide-left" id="information" role="tabpanel">
```

Comment: Hi Omer - Yes this is certainly working, but there is a small issue, like - when it is redirecting it momentarily displays the 1st tab and then it moves on the expected tab. to access the `$tab` I have used - `$tab=$_GET['tab'];` is it possible to address this issue.

Comment: can you add your all code including javascript because i think you are activating the first tab with `.show()` and then the second tab is called depending on the `$tab` value, as i tested it and it does not show any other tab than the selected one @Joshi

Comment: Ok I have update the view all relevant section as well controller action. Please tell me, if you need any more info.

Comment: Thanks Omer. That's brilliant. That fixed the issue correctly.

Comment: Hi Omer, I am facing a similar issue at another instance. can you please have a look at it. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50004982/yii2-getting-the-url-id-in-redirect-in-create-action

Comment: sure @Joshi i will reply once i reach home

Answer (score 0):

If your controller knows which tab to open, pass it as a parameter to your view:

```
return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
        'activeTab' => ...
    ]);
```

Then in your view do something along the lines of

```
<li class="<?= $activeTab == 'xyz' ? 'active' : '' ?>" ...
```

Comment: No I think there is some misunderstanding.Like my initial view is gridview in tab3. from there I click on edit, the form shows in another window. from there when I click submit/update it should redirect back to tab3. `$this->redirect(['user/update-instructor', 'id' => $model->instructor_id, '#' => 'instructor_schedule']);` so actually tab3= `instructor_schedule`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Muhammed.Omer.Aslam answer, due to different versions of JQUERY you may get a console error as

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ....
```

My self am using

```
$js=<<<JS 
          $('#dynamic-form .nav-tabs a[href="#$tab\\"]').tab('show');
 JS;

Reference  https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/2885
```