# Yii2 getting the url ID in redirect. in create action

Tags: php, yii2

like I have a view index.php(Gridview)- linked to a Menu Manage Instructor.

from there I click on edit for a specific instructor.

The URL I get is like:

`admin/user/update-instructor?id=11`

In this page I have multiple tabs, one tab is `instructor_schedule`, which is again a grid view with add records button on top.
I can add records clicking on add record without any issue.

My problem is now I want the form page redirect back to the page

`admin/user/update-instructor?id=11`

How I can achieve that?

I have tried like:

`return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor','id' => $model->id]);`

and

`return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor','id' => $model->instructor_id]);`

but I am getting the error missing information `id`.

Thanks.

action Create(ClassDurationController):

```
public function actionCreate() {
        $model = new ClassDuration();
    $count = count(Yii::$app->request->post('ClassDuration', []));

                $classdurations[] =new ClassDuration();
                for($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
                $classdurations[] = new ClassDuration();
            }


    //if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
             if (Model::loadMultiple($classdurations, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($classdurations)) {

                  foreach ($classdurations as $classduration) {
                         // var_dump($classdurations);
                      $classduration->instructor_id=$_POST['ClassDuration'][0]['instructor_id'];
                      $classduration->save(false);
                      }                 

        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('successClass');

        //return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor','id' => $model->id]);
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
        'classdurations' => $classdurations,
    ]);
}
```

Action Update(ClassDurationController):

```
public function actionUpdate($id,$tab='information') {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);

                $wd_instructor = ClassDuration::find('instructor_id')->where(['id'=>$id])->One();
                $wd_instructor_id = $wd_instructor->instructor_id;
                $classdurations = ClassDuration::find()->where(['instructor_id'=>$wd_instructor_id])->all();

                if (Model::loadMultiple($classdurations, Yii::$app->request->post()) && Model::validateMultiple($classdurations)) {
                     foreach($classdurations as $classduration){
                        $classduration->location_id=$_POST['ClassDuration'][0]['location_id'];
                        $classduration->save(false);
                    }
            Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('successClass');

            // return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                        return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor', 'id' => $model->instructor_id, 'tab' => 'instructor_schedule']);
        }

        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,    
                        'workingdays' => $classdurations,
        ]);
    }
```

ActionUpdateInstructor:

```
public function actionUpdateInstructor($id,$tab='information') {
        $model = User::findOne($id);
        $uploadPath = 'web/instructor/' . $id;
        if (!file_exists($uploadPath)) {
            mkdir($uploadPath);
        }
        $profile = Instructor::find()->where(['user_id' => $id])->one();

        if ($profile) {
            $instructor_profile = $profile;
        } else {
            $instructor_profile = new Instructor;
            $instructor_profile->user_id = $id;
        }
        if ($id == 1) {
            $cls = 'hide';
        } else {
            $cls = '';
        }
        $title = "Update";

        $modelsRest = $model->rest;
        $modelsBreakTime = $model->breakTime;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($model);
        }
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $instructor_profile->load($_POST)) {
            Yii::$app->response->format = 'json';
            return \yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm::validate($instructor_profile);
        }
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $instructor_profile->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

            $oldIDs = ArrayHelper::map($modelsRest, 'id', 'id');

            $modelsRest = Model::createMultiple(RestDays::classname(), $modelsRest);
            Model::loadMultiple($modelsRest, Yii::$app->request->post());

            $deletedIDs = array_diff($oldIDs, array_filter(ArrayHelper::map($modelsRest, 'id', 'id')));

            if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
                Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
                return ArrayHelper::merge(
                    ActiveForm::validateMultiple($modelsRest),

                    ActiveForm::validate($model),
                    ActiveForm::validate($instructor_profile)
                );
            }

            if (trim($model->password) != '') {
                $model->setPassword($model->password);
            }

            $model->username = $model->email;

            $model->save();

            if ($model->user_role != '') {
                $assign = AuthAssignment::find()->where(['user_id' => $model->id])->One();
                $assign->item_name = $model->user_role;

                $assign->save();

            }
            $instructor_profile->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($instructor_profile, 'file');
            $instructor_profile->user_id = $model->id;

            if ($instructor_profile->file != '') {
                $instructor_profile->instructor_image = time() . '.' . $instructor_profile->file->extension;
            }

            $instructor_profile->save(false);

            if ($instructor_profile->file != '') {

                $uploadPath = 'web/instructor/' . $instructor_profile->user_id;
                if (!file_exists($uploadPath)) {
                    mkdir($uploadPath);
                }

                $instructor_profile->file->saveAs($uploadPath . '/' . $instructor_profile->instructor_image);

            }
            $valid = $model->validate();
            $valid = Model::validateMultiple($modelsRest) && $valid;

            if ($valid) {
                $transaction = \Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();
                try {
                    if ($flag = $model->save(false)) {
                        if (!empty($deletedIDs)) {
                            RestDays::deleteAll(['id' => $deletedIDs]);
                        }

                        foreach ($modelsRest as $modelRests) {
                            $modelRests->instructor_id = $model->id;
                            if (!empty($modelRests->from_date) && !($flag = $modelRests->save(false))) {
                                $transaction->rollBack();
                                break;

                            }
                        }

                    }
                    if ($flag) {
                        $transaction->commit();
                        //return $this->redirect(['view-instructor', 'id' => $model->id]);
                                                return $this->redirect(['instructor']);
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $transaction->rollBack();
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('update_instructor', [
            'model' => $model,
            'modelsRest' => (empty($modelsRest)) ? [new RestDays] : $modelsRest,

            'instructor_profile' => $instructor_profile,
            'title' => $title,
            'cls' => $cls,

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: show your actionUpdateIntrstuctor  code please

Comment: @scaisEdge - Updated all the action code including the one you suggested to add.

Comment: strange.. th error message seems not related  to the code  ..    in your message error you have ID but in your code you have correctly id  .. could you please show the exact error message ?

Comment: No. I am not getting the ID in the URL. what I have shown in the first line i.e. `admin/user/update-instructor?id=11` from where I am going to the create action. after submitting the form I am getting the URL like - `admin/user/update-instructor` and with error - `Bad Request (#400)` - Missing required parameters: id

Comment: I'm referring to this "error missing information ID."  . .. why you have ID uppercase  ..  ?

Comment: that is a type/mistake from my end. yes it should be `id` actually.

Comment: if it was related to the action parameter `id` it should have thrown something like `Missing required parameters: id` can you confirm the exact exception, also can you confirm by changing the url to `/user/update-instructor` from `user/update-instructor` in the `redirect()`, and override `beforeAction()` function in your controller and add `die()` in the start of the function and check does it land on that `controller`.

Comment: yes this is the exact like after redirect the URL like - `admin/user/update-instructor` there is nothing else in the URL except that. and with error - Bad Request (#400) - `Missing required parameters: id`

Comment: that means it is redirecting from somewhere else not from that redirect line of code you have provided above.

Comment: did you changed your line `$this->redirect(['user/update-instructor','id' => $model->id]);` to `$this->redirect(['/user/update-instructor','id' => $model->id]);`

Comment: No, presently it is - ` return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor', 'id' => $model->instructor_id, 'tab' => 'instructor_schedule']);`

Comment: can you try with the suggested and see if it lands on the controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action Create(ClassDurationController) you assign to $model only

```
$model = new ClassDuration();
```

Maybe you should insert another variable to get id from parent or

```
return $this->redirect(['user/update-instructor','id' => $_POST['ClassDuration'][0]['instructor_id']]);
```

Comment: Yes that did worked as expected, but I had tried like that, but it didn't worked, may be missed something. Thanks though.